# "The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable" due to extra parentheses

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I know why the following code doesn't compile:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      main((null)); // this is fine!
      (main(null)); // this is NOT!
   }
}
```

What I'm wondering is why my compiler (javac 1.6.0_17, Windows version) is complaining "The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable".

I'd expect something like "Don't put parentheses around a method invokation, dummy!", instead.

So why is the compiler making a totally unhelpful complaint about something that is blatantly irrelevant?

Is this the result of an ambiguity in the grammar? A bug in the compiler?

If it's the former, could you design a language such that a compiler would never be so off-base about a syntax error like this?

---

Okay, I just checked and apparently this complaint is only seen from within Eclipse. If I compile from the command line, it gives the more sensible "Not a statement" error. The mystery deepens.

Comment: Not very mysterious. Eclipse uses its own compiler, not `javac`. (I've updated my answer with more details. :-P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version must be wonky. :-P When tested on OpenJDK (as distributed with Ubuntu 9.10), this is what I get:

```
ParensTest.java:4: not a statement
        (main(null));
        ^
1 error
```

---

Update based on OP's edit: Eclipse uses its own Java compiler, called `ecj`; it does not use the JDK compiler (`javac`). That is why you get different output sometimes. (And yes, the bytecode generated is sometimes different too, causing funky [differences in behaviour](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300133) depending on whether you compiled your code in Eclipse.)

(As an aside, another difference between `ecj` and `javac` in my experience: `javac` will tell you to get lost if you have a string constant over 65535 bytes long (this is a limitation in the class file format). `ecj` will actually try to emulate such a long string constant, by piecing together shorter parts, each fitting within the 64k limit, with a `StringBuilder`, then finally interning the result---just as would happen with a "real" string constant.)

Answer (score 3):

Java compiler messages are generally very unhelpful. They only really make sense to compiler writers.

From a parser perspective, it gets an expression and gets to the point where the only legal thing left to do is assign it to a variable, and there isn't one, so it gives up.

Could you design more helpful compiler messages? I suppose, but I doubt Sun/Oracle would regard that as a high priority.